# What is the Gradle Jar task equivalent to Ant's Jar task "includesFile" and "excludesFile" properties?

Tags: java, gradle, jar

[Ant's `jar` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) includes the following two properties:

- *includesfile*: Name of a file. Each line of this file is taken to be an include pattern
- *excludesfile*: Name of a file. Each line of this file is taken to be an exclude pattern

Is there an equivalent to this functionality that works for [Gradle's `Jar` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html)? I see a couple of different `include` parameters, but none that take a file.

Comment: It's Gradle - read your file and call include/exclude.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Are you willing to turn that into an answer?